# al compilar me dice dejo de funcionar. punteros y vectores

Tags: c

cargar un vector con 25 elementos como maximo , y luego a los valores de ese vector definir cuales son pares e impares ,  guardarlos en dos vectores diferentes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 25


void cargarvector(int vec[N],int tam);
void mostrarvec(int vec[N], int tam);
void seleccionar(int vec[],int vecA[],int vecB[] ,int *cantVA,int *cantVB,int tam);


int main()
{
    int vector[N],cant,vectorA[N],cantVA=0,vectorB[N],cantVB=0;
    printf("ingrese cantidad de valores para el vector 1 : ");
    scanf("%d",&cant);

    cargarvector(vector,cant);
    printf("\n");
    printf("vector 1\n");
    mostrarvec(vector,cant);
    seleccionar(vector,cant,vectorA,vectorB,&cantVA,&cantVB);
    printf("\n");
    mostrarvec(vectorA,cantVA);
    mostrarvec(vectorB,cantVB);

    return 0;
}
void cargarvector(int vec[N],int tam){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
        printf("ingrese los valores que desee : ");
        scanf("%d",&vec[i]);

}
}

void mostrarvec(int vec[N],int tam){
    int i;
    printf("[");
    for( i=0;i<tam;i++){
            printf("%d",vec[i]);


    }
    printf("]");

}

void seleccionar(int vec[],int vecA[],int vecB[],int *cantVA,int *cantVB,int cant){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cant;i++){

        if(vec[i]%2==0){
            vecA[*cantVA]=vec[i];
            (*cantVA)++;


        }else{
            vecB[*cantVB]=vec[i];
            (*cantVB)++;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes esta función:

```
void seleccionar(int vec[],int vecA[],int vecB[] ,int *cantVA,int *cantVB,int tam);
```

Y luego haces esta llamada:

```
seleccionar(vector,cant,vectorA,vectorB,&cantVA,&cantVB);
```

Si lo revisas un poco verás que los parámetros están mezclados de mala manera. Lo esperable (entiendo) debería ser esto:

```
seleccionar(vector,vectorA,vectorB,&cantVA,&cantVB,cant);
```

Intenta leer los mensajes de error y advertencias que recibes al compilar... son de gran ayuda!!! Y tampoco estaría mal que aprendieses a usar un depurador de código... programar sin saber depurar el código es como tener un coche y no saber conducir...